# Issues launching headless soundboard script on boot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

I'm building a headless soundboard using Raspberry Pi, and as such need a way to launch the script I'm using on boot. The program was edited and tested using the default editor Pi shot up, Thonny, and everything seems to run as intended. The buttons I'm using all play the sounds I expect them to, no issues.

I went ahead and edited `rc.local` to run the script as soon as the Pi boots (specifically, I added `sudo python /filepath/soundboard.py &` above `exit 0`), which it does. It seems to run identically to the way it did using Thonny, but sound cuts off after about 5 seconds, even if no buttons are pressed. When I run it directly through the command line, the same issue occurs.

The code here has been compressed, as there is more than one button, but they all use the same line.

```
import pygame
import random
import glob
from gpiozero import Button
import time

pygame.init()

while True:

    n = glob.glob('/filepath/*.wav')

    btn_0 = Button(8)

    btn_0.when_pressed = pygame.mixer.stop
    btn_0.when.held = lambda: pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(n)).play()
```

As far as I can tell, the `while` loop continues to run the program, but pressing buttons does nothing. Also, since adding the loop, the code dumps a Traceback, showing the error

`gpiozero.exc.GPIOPinInUse: pin 8 is already in use by <gpiozero.Button objext on pin GPIO8, pull_up=True, is_active=False>`

which might have something to do with my issue? `btn_0` isn't the only button to have two functions assigned to it, but the only one to throw up this error, no matter what pin I use. The error doesn't appear if I remove the loop from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You create btn_0 in an infinit while loop again and again. In the second iteration btn_0 is probably the first button that is created again. But pin 8 (which should be used for the button) has been assigned to the old instance of btn_0 in the last iteration.

You should move the glob.glob statement and the button initialization outside of the While loop. If the while loop is necessary to keep you program running place it below the initialization code and iterate over nop ore pause statements (whatever works).
If `pygame.init` starts it own looped thread you do not need a while loop at the end at all.

I don't know anything about pygame, so the last statement is just a guess.

Example:

```
import pygame
import random
import glob
from gpiozero import Button
import time

pygame.init()

n = glob.glob('/filepath/*.wav')

btn_0 = Button(8)

btn_0.when_pressed = pygame.mixer.stop
btn_0.when.held = lambda: pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(n)).play()

while True: 
    nop
```